# Select Element Within HTML Template and Append to Body

Tags: jquery, html

I have a lot of elements that I need to display for mobile users, and plan to wrap all content within a `template`, and then select the specific `div` I would like and append it to the `body`.

Why does the code below not append the `div` to the `body` as I would usually expect? I have used the most basic examples from other SO questions with no avail.

```
<template id="template">
    <div id="page1">page1</div>
    <div id="page2">page2</div>
</template>
```

And then jQuery:

```
function change_page(page_id){
    var target = "#"+page_id;
    var clone = $("#template").html();
    $("body").append(clone.find(target));
}
```

Comment: For one, JavaScript is cAsE sEnSiTiVe

Comment: Ignore the small case sensitive points, I think I've edited to correct it now.

Comment: @karthick template is html template tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp&ved=2ahUKEwjv8MHL1vjhAhW2SxUIHcumD0QQFjAPegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2stm6UIKH_Y7pba5bSjJHY

Comment: `function` needs a small `f`

Comment: `clone` is a string (which does not have a `find` method; it should be giving you an error in your console). Note that jQuery does have a [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method you can use to actually clone an element...

Comment: at first html() return contents so you cannot use find() on a string
use .clone() then on append .html()

````
var card = $(id).clone();
$(document).on('body').append(card.find(elem).html());
````

Comment: @RalphMirasol `on('body')` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(clone).find('whatever');
```

So long as `clone` contains html, and the `whatever` is a valid selector for an element in that html, you can find elements that way.  The key being you have to parse the html to dom elements first, which `$(html)` does.

```js
var template = $('#template').html();
$( document.body ).append( $(template).filter('#page2') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="template">
<div id="page1">page1</div>
<div id="page2">page2</div>
</template>
```

However, given your template has two elements at the top level, you have to use `filter()` instead of `find()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this, the filter part was the bit I was getting wrong, back to basics!